# Openmpi on Fedora 21

Tags: fedora, yum, openmpi, fedora-21, dnf

I am trying to compile some code in Fedora 21 using 'mpif90'.

First I install openmpi with 'yum':

```
[root@localhost Inversion]# yum install openmpi
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Package openmpi-1.8.3-2.fc21.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But then when I compile using 'make' it doesn't work:

```
[root@localhost Inversion]# make all
mpif90 -O3 -c src/dispersion.f90
make: mpif90: Command not found
Makefile:18: recipe for target 'obj' failed
make: *** [obj] Error 127
```

As you can see I've downloaded openmpi package but it wont compile.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot compile because you haven't loaded the necessary module.

You need to load the environmental module, this is how Fedora is handling openmpi when you install it using:

```
dnf install openmpi
```

(in Fedora 25)

Just follow the following steps:

1. In your terminal, do:

   ```
   module avail
   ```

   You should see an output something like this:

   ```
   --------------------- /usr/share/Modules/modulefiles ----------------------
   dot         module-git  module-info modules     null        use.own
   ---------------------------- /etc/modulefiles -----------------------------
   mpi/openmpi-x86_64
   ```

   Notice there is the `mpi/openmpi-x86_64` module available for you to 'load'.
2. In your terminal, you just do:

   ```
   module load mpi/openmpi-x86_64
   ```
3. Now you have access to all the mpi compilers like `mpif90` and `mpic++` etc.  You can see that the compiler binaries are stored in: `/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin`:

   ```
   $ which mpif90
   ```

   and you see the output is:

   ```
   /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpif90
   ```

Answer (score 3):

```
dnf whatprovides "*/mpif90"
```

tells you what package provides this binary. In Fedora, you can get it from `openmpi-devel` or `mpich` packages. So running

```
yum install openmpi-devel
```

should do the job for you.